# WSO2 IS 5.3.0 New API and last login time

Tags: wso2-identity-server

To register my user, I'm using the new REST API.
I had to disable :

`<EventListener type="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.listener.UserOperationEventListener" name="org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.IdentityMgtEventListener" orderId="50" enable="false"/>`

And now I don't have last Login Time set in database anymore.
I read that to have it work, I have to activate old listener :
[Enable last login and last password modified timestamps](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+Users)

`<EventListener type="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.listener.UserOperationEventListener" name="org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.IdentityMgtEventListener" orderId="50" enable="true"/>`

Is there a way to have it set with new rest API ?

Can I put the old listener after the new one in order > 97 ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use both IdentityMgtEventListeners at once. You can enable Lock Idle Accounts feature. Then it will set last login time.

Thanks
Isura.